# Кеш на сервере на отдельном диске

Tags: hdd

Есть сервер с рейд 10 - 2TB*16 обычных sata дисков 7200rpm. Этого не хватает для быстрой отдачи в пик. Хочу диск, на который будет держать основные файлы, чтобы они отдавались с диска чтобы разгрузить рейд.

Посоветуйте что-то по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант) http://hotline.ua/computer/zhestkie-diski/23976/

Answer (score 0):

Вместо жесткого диска лучше взять ssd для кэша и поставить и настроить flashcache. Про flashcache можно прочитать тут https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/blob/master/doc/flashcache-sa-guide.txt